# Update properties files when there're up-to-date data

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a Map that contains key:value data for properties that are in different properties files. I came to the following solution:

```
//firstProp - properties file
//FIRST_PROPERTIES_FILE - path to a properties file
public void changeProps(Map<String, String> props) {
    boolean isFirstPropsChanged = false;
    boolean isSecondPropsChanged = false;
    boolean isThirdPropsChanged = false;

    Set<String> keys = props.keySet();
    for(String key : keys) {
        if(firstProp.containsKey(key) && !firstProp.getProperty(key).equals(props.get(key))) {
            firstProp.setProperty(key, props.get(key));
            if(!isDirstPropsChanged) {
                isFirstPropsChanged = true;
            }
        }

        if(secondProp.containsKey(key) && !secondProp.getProperty(key).equals(props.get(key))) {
            secondProp.setProperty(key, props.get(key));
            if(!isSecondPropsChanged) {
                isSecondPropsChanged = true;
            }
        }

        if(thirdProp.containsKey(key) && !thirdProp.getProperty(key).equals(props.get(key))) {
            thirdProp.setProperty(key, props.get(key));
            if(!isThirdPropsChanged) {
                isThirdPropsChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        if(isFirstPropsChanged){
            firstProp.store(new FileOutputStream(FIRST_PROPERTIES_FILE), null);
        }
        if(isSecondPropsChanged) {
            secondProp.store(new FileOutputStream(SECOND_PROPERTIES_FILE), null);
        }
        if(isThirdPropsChanged) {
            thirdProp.store(new FileOutputStream(THIRD_PROPERTIES_FILE), null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This solution works well, but it looks like wheelchair. I looked through different DPs, Strategy seemed to be good here, but it only seemed... I even think that no DP should be applied and that there's much delicate and simpler solution. But what it is in fact?

**Updated**
Refactoring according to Brian Agnew suggestion or smth. alike.

```
//Map<Properties, File> propertiesFileMap - Properties files with File they are located at.
public void changePropsArray(Map<String, String> props) {
    Set<String> keys = props.keySet();
    for(String key : keys) {
        for(Properties prop : propertiesFileMap.keySet()) {
            if(prop.containsKey(key) && !prop.getProperty(key).equals(props.get(key))) {
                prop.setProperty(key, props.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        for(Map.Entry<Properties, File> entry : propertiesFileMap.entrySet()) {
            entry.getKey().store(new FileOutputStream(entry.getValue()), null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the matter with maintaining an array of Properties + their corresponding filename ? If you encapsulate these in an object then you simply have to loop through and that object will know how to update and write itself out.

Comment: I think I got your suggestion (see update) :) This looks much more preferable.

Comment: That better, although I'd go further and wrap the Map<Properties,File> into an object and invoke methods on that directly. Looking good though!